# How to set Content-Type of Supertest attachment

Tags: node.js, supertest

I came across a problem in my app that the `Content-Type` associated with an uploaded file was wrong if the file was sent from Microsoft Windows, giving `application/octet-stream`, while it was okay if sent from Mac, giving `text/csv`. After fixing my code to not rely on the mime type from the request, I would like to simulate that condition in one of my tests.

Given the following request, that includes JSON-stringified form fields and a file attachment, [using supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest):

```
  request(app)
    .post('/some/where')
    .field('someFormData', JSON.stringify(formData))
    .attach('someFile', 'someFile.csv')
    .expect(400)
    .end(done);
```

How can I change the **Content-Type** for the attached file? Looking at Edge's Network tab, I would like to see the following for the request above:

```
-----------------------------7e13121340602
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="someFormData"

{.............}
-----------------------------7e13121340602
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="someFile"; filename="someFile.csv"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

ÿØÿà
```

(The JSON string has been omitted with dots)

(Instead of showing `text/csv`, I want to simulate the wrong content type.)

Answer (score 6):

Using attach's **contentType** option works for me:

```
request(app)
    .post('/validateCertificate')
    .set('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data')
    .field('passphrase', '1234')
    .attach(
      'pfx',
      './src/build-request/test-certs/correct.pfx',
      { contentType: 'application/x-pkcs12' },
    )
    .expect(200))
```

Or if you're sending a buffer as the file:

```
request(app)
    .post('/validateCertificate')
    .set('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data')
    .field('passphrase', '1234')
    .attach(
      'pfx',
      buffer,
      { contentType: 'application/x-pkcs12', filename: 'correct.pfx' },
    )
    .expect(200))
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, server responds with "File missing in the request" if I remove `{ contentType: 'application/x-pkcs12' }` it works (file gets uploaded without my desired content-type). So I'm still unable to set my desired content-type

Comment: Setting `filename` option alongside `contentType` option worked for me. Updating the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
request(app)
    .post('/some/where')
    .field('someFormData', JSON.stringify(formData))
    .set('Content-Type',  'application/octet-stream')
    .attach('someFile', 'someFile.csv')
    .expect(400)
    .end(done);
```

Comment: Hi, that doesn't work. I still get the original content type. My `req` object (using Sails.js) has the following inside `req.headers`: `'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------709895074853423540687894'`

Answer (score 0):

Use .set() to set whatever Content-Type you want. Or any kind of header.

Comment: Hi, that works if you have a simple request like:
`.post('/wherever').set('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream').send('hello');` but if you use .field, it becomes a `multipart/form-data`